# How to check if all elements in a list are the same

Tags: python, list

I am trying to produce a score depending on whether all elements in the list are the same.

```
totals = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

So if all elements are the same (like in the example above) the score will be 40.

I tried with:

```
count.same(totals)
```

Comment: What on earth did you expect `count.same` to do? Where is `count` defined? Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Create a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and check the length. A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

```
if len(set(totals)) == 1:
    score = 40
```

Demonstration

```
>>> totals = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> print(set(totals))
{1}
>>> totals = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
>>> print(set(totals))
{1, 2}
```

Comment: Using a `set` requires all the elements to be hashable. If `totals` is a list of lists, then you can't make a `set` out of them.

Comment: Correct. And if the questioner had mentioned some datastructure like that, I would have provided a different solution 7 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by the scoring as you don't discuss how you arrive at the score of 40. However, one way of checking if all elements in a list are the same would be:

```
totals.count(totals[0]) == len(totals)
```

This simply returns `True` if they are all the same or `False` if not.

Comment: Now that I have seen @Matthias's answer I think this is a slightly simpler cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create your simple function?

```
def all_equal(totals):
    if len(totals) > 1:
        start = totals[0] # compare with the first element
        for i in range(1, len(totals)):
            if totals[i] != start:
                 return False
    return True
#
totals = [12, 14, 28]
totals_2 = [12, 12, 12]

print(all_equal(totals))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all(x == totals[0] for x in totals[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using iterators means that your code will work with generator expressions (which do not support [0] indexing), and still do early exit if the 2nd out of a million entries differs from the first:

```
def all_the_same(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    try:
        first = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("empty sequence") from None
    return all(obj == first for obj in it)


for seq in [
    [1]*1_000_000,
    [1]*1_000_000 + [2],
    (x for x in [1]*1_000_000),
    (x for x in [1] * 1_000_000 + [2]),
    [],
]:
    print(seq)
    print(all_the_same(seq))
    print()
```

prints:

```
[1, 1, 1,...]
True

[1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 2]
False

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000024BA0DD2110>
True

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000024BA0DD0510>
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not good idea but it is also a solution.

```
In [272]: len(totals)*[0] == [totals.index(i) for i in totals]
Out[272]: True
```